# Migration to Weblogic and EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, sequence

> I have to migrate my application from webshere to weblogic. When I
>   deploy the ear of my application on WebLogic I obtain this errore:
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Substituted for missing class
>   Exception [EclipseLink-7299] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd) - org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: Conflicting annotations with the same name [idSequence]
>   were found. The first one
>   [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({name=idSequence,
>   sequenceName=SEQUENCE_TRANSAZIONI})] was found within [class 
>   it.sia.gestoreposizioni.bo.repository.transazioni.Transazioni] and the
>   second [@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator({name=idSequence,
>   sequenceName=GP_SEQUENCE})] was found within [class 
>   it.sia.gestoreposizioni.bo.repository.soap.SoapUsers]. Named
>   annotations must be unique across the persistence unit.

```
//My java Classes:
@Entity
@Table(name = "GP_TRANSAZIONI")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "Transazioni.findIdTransazioneByPosizione", query = "SELECT distinct(t.identificativoTransazione) FROM Transazioni t WHERE t.posizione.id = ?1") 
})
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_TRANSAZIONI", name = "idSequence")
public class Transazioni extends AbstractIdEntity {
    ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "GP_SOAP_USERS")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "SoapUsers.authenticate", query = "SELECT su FROM SoapUsers su WHERE su.username = ?1 and su.secret = ?2")
})
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "GP_SEQUENCE", name = "idSequence")
public class SoapUsers extends AbstractIdEntity {
    ...

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractIdEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "idSequence")
    @Column(name = "OBJ_ID")
    private Long id;
    ...
```

In Transazioni class and in SoapUsers class there is the same sequence (idSequence). Both classes inherit from AbstractIdEntity where is defined idSequence

Comment: Firstly, if you want to use SEQUENCE then you should set your strategy to SEQUENCE. AUTO means "let the JPA provider decide" (and it doesnt have to use a SEQUENCE then). Secondly, the JPA spec doesn't define inheritance of sequence generators, so a JPA provider does not have to support what you are trying to do anyway. None of this is anything to do with WebLogic either ... it is JPA and EclipseLink (the JPA provider you have chosen to use)

Comment: I haven't choosen EclipseLink as JPA provider. Application server weblogic impose it. When I deploied my app on WebSphere or WildFly I hadn't EclipseLink and so no error with jpa entities. I'd like to force javax.persistence as JPA provider instead of EclipseLink in Weblogic application server. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Errm, specify it in `persistence.xml` like the JPA spec says to do ... but that doesnt escape the fact that you are doing JPA-provider-specific nonsense in your configuration/mapping